# TByteDynArray para String Delphi 7

Tags: array, delphi

Tenho um metodo para converter um arquivo em base64 que retorna um TByteDynArray, e queria converter esse TByteDynArray para String.

Ja tentei de algumas maneiras e não vem dando certo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Erro : [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

```
function Converter(P: TByteDynArray): string;
begin
  SetLength(Result, Length(P));
  System.Move(P[0], Result[1], Length(P));
end;
```

Tente fazer assim:

Fonte: http://www.devmedia.com.br/forum/converter-tbytedynarray-para-string/351139

Comment: Lima, conseguiu resolver?